# After user login Page Refresh is not working for Passport js

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am using the following code to authenticate users with passport js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

var config = require('./config');

var User = require('./models/user');

var passport = require('passport'),
    FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

//setting up passport
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    });
});


passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.development.fb.appid,
        clientSecret: config.development.fb.appSecret,
        callbackURL: config.development.fb.url + 'fbauthed'
    },

    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({
            'fbId': profile.id
        }, function (err, oldUser) {
            if (oldUser) {
                console.log('Existing user: ' + oldUser.name + ' found and logged in');
                done(null, oldUser);
            } else {
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.fbId = profile.id;
                newUser.name = profile.displayName;
                newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                newUser.username = profile.username;
                console.log(profile);

                newUser.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('New user:' + newUser.name + 'created and logged in');
                    done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    }

));


app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'big secret'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/fbauth', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: 'email'}));
app.get('/fbauthed', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ failureRedirect: '/'}), routes.loggedin);

app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect('/');
});
//app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The above code works great for when users are authenticating, however after authentication a page refresh throws an error like below.

```
Express
500 failed to obtain access token (status: 400 data: {"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}})
at /home/colm/javascript/facebookauth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth2.js:125:38
at exports.OAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken (/home/colm/javascript/facebookauth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:131:18)
at passBackControl (/home/colm/javascript/facebookauth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:77:9)
at IncomingMessage.exports.OAuth2._request.request.on.callbackCalled (/home/colm/javascript/facebookauth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:94:7)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1447:20)
at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:544:27)
at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:898:20)
```

What is causing this and how can I fix this problem?
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The error message _tells_ you what’s the reason …

Comment: CBroe perhaps I should just read them more closely next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route which is used to handle the FB callback should only issue a redirect (either back to the login page if the authentication failed, or the 'logged in' page when authentication succeeded).

You're calling `routes.loggedin` to handle that route (in case of success):

```
app.get('/fbauthed', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ failureRedirect: '/'}), routes.loggedin);
```

This will keep all the tokens passed by FB in the URL resulting in the 'This authorization code has been used' message.

So try this:

```
app.get('/loggedin', ensureLoggedIn('/'), routes.loggedin); // see below
app.get('/fbauthed', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ 
  failureRedirect: '/',
  successRedirect: '/loggedin'
}));
```

[`ensureLoggedIn`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login) is a middleware that will check if the user is logged in, and if not, will redirect to `/` (or whatever URL you like).

Comment: Thanks robertklep. That has sorted it.

Comment: hi @robertklep , should I use passport.authenticate() or req.isAuthenticated() to check isLoggin ?

Comment: @AquariusPotter purely using Passport, I think you can only check for the existence of `req.user` to check if a request belongs to a logged-in user or not.